# Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url !?(Laravel-Api to React(SPA) )

Tags: laravel, authentication, axios, laravel-sanctum

I have a react frontend with in localhost:3000 and laravel API in localhost:8000 and want to set up an auth system with sanctum (statful), up to the documentation of laravel(https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) a cookies should set up after this get request:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  });

    api.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
```

Even the header response contain a set-cookie values, they are no cookie setting up!
It's because the top level domain that appear for me correct.

[image: response header]

this is in my .env of laravel

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

I try to build an auth system that based on laravel cookie, but these cookies doesn't establish and I do not know the problem, I hope helping me get and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the domain to your `config/sanctum.php` file.

From the documentation:

> If you are accessing your application via a URL that includes a port (127.0.0.1:8000), you should ensure that you include the port number with the domain.

So be sure that your domain appears there, like this:
[image]

Comment: it's already set up, exactly like your code.